# Python - Looping Statement Syntax

Tags: python, loops, syntax

New to Python. Working in the following environment.

Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

I'm getting an "invalid syntax" error on the following line of code:

`if(j % 10000) == 0`

Pretty sure this is something simple. Just not familiar enough to know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: if j % 10000 == 0: #next line needs to be indented

Comment: Thanks Heiner. I played around a bit with your answer. Looks like I was missing the colon at the end. Looking at the rest of the sample code, I take it the colon is read as "Then" in an "If-Then" statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `:` at the end of the line, and the line (or block) after must be indented.

```
if(j % 10000) == 0:
    # loop code
```

Comment: Thanks Mij. Appreciate the feedback.